# Only author's initials in BibTeX natbib using named style

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a BibTeX file with a mix of entries, some with full author's names and some with just initials. I would like my typeset bibliography to only use initials. Is there a way to do this?

I have the following BibTeX commands currently in my file:

```
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib} 
\bibliography{thesis}
\bibliographystyle{named}
```

I have found documentation on how to do this with biblatex, but not with natbib.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Copy the file `named.bst` (in TeXLive it is in `texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/beebe/named.bst`) to the file `abbrvnamed.bst` in your working directory.
2. Find in this file the line

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.names}
   ```

   and inside the function the line

   ```
     { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
   ```
3. Change this line to

   ```
     { s nameptr "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
   ```

Now you can put in your document `\bibliographystyle{abbrvnamed}`, and get the result you want.

For the curious: in this magic line `ff` means Full First names, `f.` means abbreviated First names, `vv` is "Von part", `ll` is for Last names, `jj` is for Junior suffix.  Yes, BibTeX language is evil.

Answer (score 13):

Now, it's even easier: just use \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} and it works like a charm.

In my file-containg-bibtex-entries.bib I have the following entry:

```
@article{Taboada2006,
author = {Taboada, Maite},
doi = {10.1016/j.pragma.2005.09.010},
issn = {03782166},
journal = {Journal of Pragmatics},
keywords = {Coherence relations,Conjunctions,Connectives,Conversation,Discourse markers,Discourse signalling,Newspaper text,RST,Rhetorical Structure Theory},
month = apr,
number = {4},
pages = {567--592},
title = {{Discourse markers as signals (or not) of rhetorical relations}},
url = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378216605002249},
volume = {38},
year = {2006}
}
```

My tex file is the following:

```
%preamble
...
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\begin{document}
According to \cite{Taboada2006}.

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{file-containing-bibtex-entries}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image: natbib with abbreviated names of authors]

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? Perhaps a minimal example showing the input and expected output under your suggestion?

Comment: I just edited my answer; I hope it's ok now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the style `abbrvnat` does *not* produce the same formatted as the `named` style (with the modifications proposed in @Boris's answer to the `format.names` function) does. For one, the `named` style does not output the fields `issn`, `doi`, and `url`, whereas `abbrvnat` does (see the screenshot you posted). In addition, `named` prints "April", whereas `abbrvnat` abbreviates the name of the month to "Apr.".