# No spacing in bibliography between author's abbreviated first and middle name for natbib

Tags: spacing, natbib

How can I get rid of the space between the author's abbreviated first and last name in `natbib`.

Ex. Chan, A. P. becomes Chan, A.P. ?

I've found that the equivalent in Biber (?) is: `\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}`

Is there an equivalent for `natbib`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this i similar to the following:
[Only author's initials in BibTeX natbib using named style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36660) or
[Abbreviated first names without spaces in between?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124990)

Basically you need to modify the format-string given to the bst function `format.name$`, for instance `"{f{.}.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` (where the important part is the `f{.}`).

Please be aware that the "-" in composite names is lost (see [abbreviated first names with no "~" but preserving "-"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409521))