# abbreviated first names with no "~" but preserving "-"

Tags: bibtex, author

I think this i similar to [Only author's initials in BibTeX natbib using named style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36660) or
[Abbreviated first names without spaces in between?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124990)

When an author has multiple first names, I need to have the initials of these names with no space or tilde in between.
E.g.: `author="Gamboz, A. B."` to `A.B. Gamboz`

The format `"{f{.}. }{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` does it, however it also removes the "-" that can be present in some French names or Japanese and Chinese transliterations.

E.g.: `author="Jean-Baptiste Poquelin"` to `J.B. Poquelin` (instead of `J.-B. Poquelin`).

Is there a way to preserve the "-"?

MWE (from pg.37 of "Tame the BeaST"):

min.bst

```
ENTRY {any}{}{}
FUNCTION {test}
{"Jean-Baptiste Poquelin"
#1 "{f{.}.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ top$}
READ
EXECUTE{test}
```

min.aux

```
\bibstyle{min}
```

then run `bibtex min`

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer to this in [BibTeX Frequently Asked Questions](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf) Q.35
proposed by Philip G. Ratcliffe on the newsgroup comp.text.tex on June 28, 2002 in the thread [BiBTeX, bst hackers, format.name$, please help](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/a4JFP9Qpc_Q/4RlNiPIhPYEJ) which consists in using a function to "manually" remove spaces

```
STRINGS {z}

FUNCTION {remove.spaces}
{ 'z :=
  ""
  { z empty$ not }
  { z #1 #1 substring$
    z #2 global.max$ substring$ 'z :=
    duplicate$ "~" =
      'pop$
      { duplicate$ " " =
          'pop$
          { * }
        if$
      }
    if$
  }
  while$
}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {forname.format.string}
{ "{f.}" }

FUNCTION {surname.format.string}
{ "{vv~}{ll}" }

FUNCTION {jnrname.format.string}
{ "{, jj}" }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr forname.format.string format.name$ remove.spaces
      duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ { "~" * } if$
      s nameptr surname.format.string format.name$ *
      s nameptr jnrname.format.string format.name$ *
      't :=
```

However, this solution will break if one has authors with accents written in the following form:

```
  author = {Greensite, Jeff and Olejn\'ik, {\v S}tefan and Zwanziger, Daniel},
```

because the space in `{\v S}` will be lost:

```
J.~Greensite, {\vS}.~Olejn\'ik and D.~Zwanziger
```

Comment: It should be `{\v{S}}tefan`

Comment: You mean in the "author" field of the bibtex record? I fully agree. However in my use case I had to take the info as it come from the internet (i.e. no control on the source), so I thought I'd mention this corner case. E.g. `curl -H 'Accept: application/x-bibtex'
https://inspirehep.net/api/literature/1516023`. I've asked INSPIRE to change the accent to `\v{S}`. Is the external group important here?

Comment: It's more important for surnames, because the missing braces will impact on sorting. About the link you show, I find it very “unusual” that one name is reported as `Rap\v cák` instead of the “correct” `Rap{\v{c}}{\'{a}}k`. Also bracing titles is wrong.

Comment: They usually do a very good job, but have some sporadic case of bad metadata. I'll report your observations, thanks.

Comment: @egreg I'm guessing the `Rap\v cák` is a relic of software written during the era of 8-bit encodings. This is especially problematic for data stored in databases where until sometime around 2008 or so it was not uncommon for the default encoding for data storage to be ISO-8859-1 which includes á but not č,

Comment: @DonHosek Let's hope that Unicode has put an end to the code page mess.

Comment: @egreg In theory it has. In practice the two biggest offenders (for the sake of backwards compatability) seem to be Windows and TeX.