# What is this bibliography style?

Tags: bibtex

What is the following style?

[image]

If I want to use this style, is there an appropriate style file? Or how to write a `bst` file according to known style file?

I only know how to make the first name abbreivated: [Only author's initials in BibTeX natbib using named style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36660/only-authors-initials-in-bibtex-natbib-using-named-style)

Comment: looks like a SIAM journal.

Comment: @percusse Nope. N. J. Higham, Handbook of Writing for the Mathematical Sciences, Society for Industrial and
Applied Mathematics, Philadelphia, PA, 1993.

Comment: @MartinWang that's yes then:-) (or at least the same society:-) I

Comment: Which journal or book does this snippet of a bibliography come from?

Comment: Separately, have you tried to familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utitility, a part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package? It provides a menu-driven question and multiple choice answer setup and, based on the answers you've provided, creates a highly customized bibliography style file.

Comment: @Mico, Thanks, I find the template from Elsevier: [elsarticle-template](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0019/166141/elsarticle-template.zip)

Comment: @Mico, `makebst` is wonderful, thanks for your advice which is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my ignorance of not searching the original publisher Elsevier:  [elsevier template](http://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0019/166141/elsarticle-template.zip).

Thanks to @Mico 's advice, and the tool `custom-bib/makebst` is very useful, which I'll use in future. With command

```
latex texmf-dist/tex/latex/custom-bib/makebst.tex
```

and interactive interface, you can custom various `.bst` style  files as you wish.